# Android: Passing Extra From newInstance to onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am pretty new to Android programming and and am trying to figure out how to use fragments. I am using a `ViewPager` to scroll between fragments. However, when I swipe to go to the next fragment, the data does not update. I get the same fragment over and over again.

The code is as follows:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by nandeeka on 6/13/16.
 */
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
    public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";
    public static final String TAG = "CrimeFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID crimeID = (UUID) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + crimeID);
        mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeID);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                mCrime.setTitle(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getFormattedDate(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        mDateButton.setEnabled(false);

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeID) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeID);
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: " + crimeID);
        CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why as I swipe from fragment to fragment, the `crimeID` does not update, meaning that the information displayed in the fragment stays the same. I know that the correct information is being passed to `newInstance`, it just does not seem to be changing in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: What value are you passing in `newInstance` on swipe?

Comment: It is a serialized ID. I guess I forgot to mention that the information getting passed to `newInstance` is is correct, but for some reason, it does not seem to change when onCreate is called.

Comment: Try using `getArguments` instead of `getActivity().getIntent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to get the data from Intent which only working with activity. Try getting your UUID with getArguments as @Apporv says.

To do that change the following code:

```
UUID crimeID = (UUID) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
```

to something like:

```
// Get passing data from bundle
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
  UUID crimeID = (UUID) bundle.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
  // Do something with your CrimeID
  } else {
   Log.d(TAG, "UUID Data not found!");
}
```